# Delete app and upload same app but what about name? iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to delete my app from the app store and upload it again. I know the Bundle ID, SKU, and name can't be the same. But lets say the first app is called "Fruit Tapper - Tap on Fruits"
I delete that app, and I upload the new version of it and call it just "Fruit Tapper" without the "Tap on Fruits" part. Would that still be considered same name?

Comment: Since "Fruit Tapper" != "Fruit Tapper - Tap on Fruits" then no, it's not the same name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wanted to be 100% sure. If anybody has tried this please respond! :)